# Printing issue with a remote RDSH server with VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, network-printer

Here is my issue.

I have many users that connect from their office to a remote 2012R2 RDSH server hosted in a Datacenter.

Between the 2 sites, we have mounted a VPN tunnel ; that works fine.

For many reasons (thinclients, printers options etc.), we dont want to use the redirected printers but direct TCP/IP printers, so the users can print from everywhere on the office printers.

Everything works but randomly, one of the printers (never the same) stops working. The document goes to the spool for 18 seconds, and goes out from it, but nothing is printed. When everything is fine, the printing takes only 3 or 4 seconds.

We have tested everything : restarting the spooler service, removing and creating another printer, removing the TCP/IP local port etc. Nothing works.

The only way to make the printer work again is to reboot the RDSH print erver or the disable/enable the netword card, but in that case, the connections fail and we have more problems with SQL, so we have to reboot the VM.

We should think that the printer IP is blacklisted by Windows until the next reboot.

All the updates and fixes are installed.

It seems that we are not the only ones to have this problem:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b25c2ca-cca2-4d2b-9742-7cc05e82b6c8/printers-stop-working-only-reboot-will-fix-server-2012-r2?forum=winserver8gen

We dont have identified a solution.

Could you help me?

Comment: Are these printers configured locally on the session host or are they shared on another host?